# „Linear Algebraic Explanation“ of Decay, Decoherence, Dephasing & Dissipation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-optics

In the literature one encounters many different versions/descriptions of general processes like decay, decoherence, dephasing and dissipation. Depending on the area (like condensed matter vs. quantum optics) quite distinct jargon is used to describe/model these phenomena. What I am really looking for is some very clear description in (almost）purely linear algebraic terms (a formalism suitable for quantum information in finite dimensions). Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (for various subsystems: tensor product space) and operator algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H^\dagger}$ (with $\mathcal{H^\dagger}$ dual space), how could each of the above terms be explained/defined in a straightforward manner without any additional (community-specific) jargon?